# Calligraphy font with latin-extende-a alphabet

Tags: fonts, xetex, extended-characters

I'm trying to write some name cards for table placements using a calligraphy font, but I needed latin-extended-a alphabet which has characters like ā, ņ, etc.

Everything suitable for the style I want in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html hasn't included latin-extended-a character set.

Is there an easy or reasonable way to work out which fonts might work?

I'm also using xelatex, so TTF/OTF system fonts are worth checking as well.

Thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: @Thérèse I'm using tex-gyre from tex live at 18651 (2.004) and that doesn't seem to be the case. I will try using escaped codes as described in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenType version of TeX Gyre Chorus has almost complete coverage of Latin Extended-A. Only four characters are missing: `U+138` (Latin Small Letter Kra), `U+0149` (Latin Small Letter N preceded by apostrophe, deprecated as of Unicode 5.2), `U+0166` (Latin Capital Letter T with stroke), and `U+0167` (Latin Small Letter T with stroke).

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}% only if compiling with lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array,fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\sffamily}{l}llllllllllllllll}
& 0 & \sffamily 1 & \sffamily 2 & \sffamily 3 & \sffamily 4 & \sffamily 5 & \sffamily 6 & \sffamily 7 & \sffamily 8 & \sffamily 9 & \sffamily A & \sffamily B & \sffamily C & \sffamily D & \sffamily E & \sffamily F\\
U+010x & Ā & ā & Ă & ă & Ą & ą & Ć & ć & Ĉ & ĉ & Ċ & ċ & Č & č & Ď & ď\\
U+011x & Đ & đ & Ē & ē & Ĕ & ĕ & Ė & ė & Ę & ę & Ě & ě & Ĝ & ĝ & Ğ & ğ\\
U+012x & Ġ & ġ & Ģ & ģ & Ĥ & ĥ & Ħ & ħ & Ĩ & ĩ & Ī & ī & Ĭ & ĭ & Į & į\\
U+013x & İ & ı & Ĳ & ĳ & Ĵ & ĵ & Ķ & ķ & ĸ & Ĺ & ĺ & Ļ & ļ & Ľ & ľ & Ŀ\\
U+014x & ŀ & Ł & ł & Ń & ń & Ņ & ņ & Ň & ň & ŉ & Ŋ & ŋ & Ō & ō & Ŏ & ŏ\\
U+015x & Ő & ő & Œ & œ & Ŕ & ŕ & Ŗ & ŗ & Ř & ř & Ś & ś & Ŝ & ŝ & Ş & ş\\
U+016x & Š & š & Ţ & ţ & Ť & ť & Ŧ & ŧ & Ũ & ũ & Ū & ū & Ŭ & ŭ & Ů & ů\\
U+017x & Ű & ű & Ų & ų & Ŵ & ŵ & Ŷ & ŷ & Ÿ & Ź & ź & Ż & ż & Ž & ž & ſ\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

Comment: Warning to the reader unfamiliar with fonts in xetex: In some cases (e.g. here - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/730232cc040d1f3bf10094749134ba6c ) the included packages might break utf-8 tex file encoding. When using macros like `\={a}` instead of ā, this can cause problems. So: don't mix xelatex with `fontenc` package and macro accent input - instead use either latex+fontenc+accent maros, OR xelatex+fontspec+accented literals. Thanks to @bluebirch for help with this...